# File gallery website software

Tags: web-apps, file-management, cms, self-hosted

So I've run some small, personal websites for a few years now, with a couple of different CMSes over that time. But I've realised that most of what I do with the website is make available files of mine (mostly software and videos) that I have created to the public at large.

So what I'm looking for is some kind of CMS focussed around, or good at making files available.

Ideally I'd be able to:

- Upload files either through the software/CMS or pull from existing file structure
- Add title, description etc.
- Add tags or a single category
- Have the public-facing front end display some relativley friendly menu of files, possibly a search function

The end result would be something like (going back in time a bit) Fileplanet or whatever. Or more modern, I guess Sourceforge/Cnet, but without all the uncessary extra steps and cruft they have.

Comment: What CMS in particular?

Comment: @rrirower Any. Currently don't have anything set up. So what I'm asking for is ideally a CMS intended for hosting a file repository/library, although I suppose a good addon for another CMS would also do the job.